# Why we need to list custom fonts in info.plist?

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

We already have project in which already added fonts is working without adding plist file but we want to add another fonts which is not working without adding in plist?

Comment: Why don't you want to add it to the plist ?

Comment: Can you add more information? What custom fonts are working without registering them in the info.plist? (Perhaps they are not custom but already included in the iOS, what is why they work without including them in the info.plist). Check the list of preinstalled fonts https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/

Comment: we are using Averta-Regular font and it is custom font.

Comment: We have already checked that it is not preinstalled fonts.

Answer (score 1):

If you use custom font in the storyboard it automatically added in the plist during compilation.

So if you doesn't used it in the storyboard it doesn't added automatically and should be added manually.